# Removing gridlines from x axis and y axis using python xlsxwriter

Tags: python, charts, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to remove gridlines from x axis and y axis which I created using xlsxwriter, and it's not working.

```
'major_gridlines': { 'visible': False}
```

[image: Current output]
The small marks coming in x and y axis. Jut needed a simple x and y axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The small marks coming in x and y axis.

Those are tick marks and in Excel they are separate from the gridlines. The can be turned off in XlsxWriter as follows:

```
chart.set_x_axis({'major_tick_mark': 'none',
                  'minor_tick_mark': 'none'})
```

See the references to `tick` in the XlsxWriter [docs on set_x_axis()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/chart.html#chart-set-x-axis).